# Parent Folder Not Found

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, folder

I have a simple library with folders. When I navigate into the library and browse deep, I can click the parent folder name in the header to navigate back up.

If I have a direct link to a folder, i.e. https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/site/documents/folder1/folder2, and I click the parent folder, I get a 404 error. I click back, click it again and it works.

Comment: I can reproduce this behavior

Comment: I've opened a ticket with MSFT when I saw it happen on another tenant of mine. Yay

Comment: This is how it was designed, they'll consider a fix. I said I want the supervisor. They're now looking into it.

Comment: Support said it's by design, and to put it on uservoice for suggesting a feature improvement..... >|